# how to process data from file using hashes in perl

Tags: perl, file-io, hash

```
#input data
11000000,        1637,        -7.8737,      -20.15022
11000001,        1634,       -710.377,      -20.150137
11000002,        1639,       -709.87366,    -20.150133
11000003,        1631,        -7.1737,      -22.650156
11000004,        1639,        709.87366,    -20.150133
11000005,        1630,       -710.6,        -22.650074
```

i want this output,print values from second column which are equal,print values from third column which are equal but have opposite sign,and also print values from fourth column which are equal.

## output should be like this::

```
1639,          709.87366,       -20.150133
```

Comment: In the example third column has not opposite sign, it simply misses 1st column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe as this:

```
while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    @datas = split/,\s+/;
    $k = sprintf "%s:%s:%s", $datas[1], abs $datas[2], $datas[3];
    print join(",\t", @datas[1..3]), "\n" if (++$hash{$k} > 1);
}

__DATA__
11000000,        1637,        -7.8737,      -20.15022
11000001,        1634,       -710.377,      -20.150137
11000002,        1639,       -709.87366,    -20.150133
11000003,        1631,        -7.1737,      -22.650156
11000004,        1639,        709.87366,    -20.150133
11000005,        1630,       -710.6,        -22.650074
```

Answer (score 3):

you can simply read the file line by line, then

```
@numbers = split /\s+/, $line;
```

*or*

```
# includes comma in the split pattern to select just the number
@numbers = split /,\s+/, $line;
```

and select

```
$numbers[1], $numbers[2], $numbers[3]
```

---

A simple script whichi prints out what you requested could be:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

open FILE, '<', 'input.txt';

foreach my $line (<FILE>)
{
  my @numbers = split /,\s+/, $line;
  printf "%d,\t%f,\t%f\n", $numbers[1], -1*$numbers[2], $numbers[3];
}

close FILE;
```

Comment: `(split /\s+/, $line)[1..3]` in one line ;)